# What do I need to do to prepare for starting a business?

Tags: investing, credit-card, savings, start-up

I have this service business that I've been working on the backend (planning, relationships, coding etc) for a couple of years but I don't know how I can get the time/money to launch it.

I work 40 hours per week, and with commuting and getting ready etc that's about 45 hours.

When my business goes live, I need to be available 24/7 at the start until it's stable enough that I can step back from it. How long that takes depends on how much I can invest in marketing.

The business is designed to be profitable from the start, I'll get about $10 net profit per customer per week (excluding only marketing).

How do I get to the point where I can quit my job and go live?

My financial situation:

```
Income $800/week net  
Rent $230/week  
All regular bills calculated (electricity, water, phone, car registration etc) $125/week  
Food & house supplies budget $90/week  
Fuel $40/week
```

Recently I had medical bills and some time off work so I've exhausted all savings. I also have a credit card debt of $4000. I pay $50 to that each week + any extra money I have leftover.

I've mostly recovered and I go back to work next week.

What should be my plan and how do I get to the point where I can launch my startup? I know I should probably try to get an investor, but I want to try to do it myself and keep ownership.

I don't have any collateral or anything I could get a big loan for, but I'd like to pay off the credit card debt and keep it as an emergency fund, and then get a small bank loan on top. I'm sure I could get $5000.

There are probably some costs I haven't considered when I go live, so I want to have some extra money for this.

I need to get 50 customers to cover my bills, and 80 to overtake my current income. It might happen within 1-3 months. This doesn't account for initial marketing cost, but after achieving this goal I can put some portion of profits back into marketing. My goal is to get marketing spending down to 5% of profits.

So I saw this list about whether I'm ready for a startup:

- Is there a market for your business idea?
- Are you a professional for that market?
- A real professional with relevant real-world experience, not just an interested amateur?
- Do you know how to find customers, suppliers and employees on that market?
- Do you have the time, money and nerves to start your business?
- Do you have the time, money and nerves to start your business if everything that could go wrong does go wrong?
- Do you still have money left to finance your personal lifestyle during that time?
- Do you have a source of income you can return to when your business fails?
- Do you know the basics of business administration (how to do a cost-benefit analysis, how to do bookkeeping, how to pay taxes as a business, which laws and regulations apply to your industry, etc.?)

I can answer yes to everything except whether I have the time and money to start the business. I don't, so how do I get to that point? And what else do I need to consider?

Comment: Starting a business is always an act of faith. Either you need to have financial reserves, or you need to find some support (financially). Spouse, friends, family members, anybody willing to lend money on low terms for extended periods if you can't bootstrap yourself. Don't forget extra expenses of being self employed, like the self-employment tax, having to pay quarterly, State and local filings, franchise taxes, etc.

Comment: I think the question is a bit too broad.  The obvious answer is just "save enough money that you can live off it for 6+ months".